# Order by Query not wrorking for large records for Pheniox

Tags: java, hbase, apache-phoenix

version of phoenix :-4.4
**i am executing a phoenix query by java code in which i was using order by when i run this query but after every 2 and 3 successful execution it shows the following error:-**

```
     java.lang.RuntimeException:     `enter code here`org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixIOException: org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixIOException:org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: coverageHole,32,1466455632193.e47a15ae26e304b1927c7afc82ec2d36.: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.createIOException(ServerUtil.java:84)
at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.throwIOException(ServerUtil.java:52)
at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.ScanRegionObserver.getTopNScanner(ScanRegionObserver.java:245)
at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.ScanRegionObserver.doPostScannerOpen(ScanRegionObserver.java:221)
at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.BaseScannerRegionObserver.postScannerOpen(BaseScannerRegionObserver.java:177)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RegionCoprocessorHost$52.call(RegionCoprocessorHost.java:1318)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RegionCoprocessorHost$RegionOperation.call(RegionCoprocessorHost.java:1673)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RegionCoprocessorHost.execOperation(RegionCoprocessorHost.java:1748)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RegionCoprocessorHost.execOperationWithResult(RegionCoprocessorHost.java:1712)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RegionCoprocessorHost.postScannerOpen(RegionCoprocessorHost.java:1313)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.scan(RSRpcServices.java:2259)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:32205)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2114)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:101)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:130)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:107)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.MappedByteBufferQueue$MappedByteBufferSegmentQueue.offer(MappedByteBufferQueue.java:209)
at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.MappedByteBufferQueue.offer(MappedByteBufferQueue.java:73)
at java.util.AbstractQueue.add(AbstractQueue.java:95)
at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.OrderedResultIterator.getResultIterator(OrderedResultIterator.java:225)
at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.OrderedResultIterator.next(OrderedResultIterator.java:169)
at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.ScanRegionObserver.getTopNScanner(ScanRegionObserver.java:240)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/CreateIssue
Create a ticket with the exact steps to reproduce. Also test using a newer version to see if it has already been fixed.